# Workflow Error: "An error has occured in [the name of my workflow]"

Tags: workflow, error

I am facing following Workflow error:

> "An error has occurred in [the name of my workflow]"

i.e. Workflow is giving `"Error Occurred"` in the status field. Usually when I go to the workflow page from a list, it gives details like `"Workflow Started"` and then the error, but in this case it just says that `"An error has occurred in [the name of my workflow]"`

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the logic of the worflow? It'll be hard to say without knowing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Can you check your ULS logs for a more detailed error? Also, what kind of workflow is it? OOB workflow? Custom Visual Studio Workflow or SPD Workflow?